# Merge contents of a hash containing array of arrays in jQuery/JS for Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, hash, highcharts

I have two hashes:

```
var hash1 = { name: "hello1", data: [ [1, 1], [2, 1] ] };
var hash2 = { name: "hello2", data: [ [3, 1], [4, 2] ] };
var hash3 = {};
```

What I would like is to combine the hash into a new one (hash3) in such a way, as to only merge the array of arrays for the data object/key. The result should ideally be sorted based on the first element of the array (which really is a time value):

```
hash3 = { name: hello1, data: [ [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 1], [4, 2] ] };
```

Prefer jQuery. But JavaScript and/or jQuery would both work.

Also, if someone could recommend a good book on manipulating data structures in JavaScript, I would appreciate it.

PS: All that manipulation is basically intended to combine two series into one for the Highcharts graphing library.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any good books about what you need, but simple solution will be to create function to merge series, see:

```
function mergeSeries(s1, s2) {
    var r = {};
    r.name = s1.name; // use first name
    r.data = s1.data.concat(s2.data); // merge arrays
    r.data.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a[0] - b[0];
    }); // sort data in series to be ascending by x-value
    return r;
}
```

Then use will be simple:

```
var hash3 = mergeSeries(hash1, hash2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind modifying `hash1` in place it's as simple as:

```
> $.merge(hash1.data, hash2.data);
> hash1
Object {name: "hello1", data: Array[4]}
```

---

If you want to leave hash1 as is:

```
> hash3 = {'name': hash1.name, 'data': $.merge($.merge([], hash1.data), hash2.data)};
> hash3
Object {name: "hello1", data: Array[4]}
```

Or:

```
> hash3 = $.extend({}, hash1);
> $.merge(hash3.data, hash2.data);
> hash3
Object {name: "hello1", data: Array[4]}
```